# Need to erase history from command prompt

Tags: windows-7

My little brother keeps looking at violent games after I finish playing them. He is so smart but I need to get him to stop.  How do I erase one or all items from history on my computer so that it doesn't show up on the command prompt? I have looked everywhere for an answer and even got to the point of making up my own.

Comment: Command prompt? Why not close it? What are you trying to say or describe?

Comment: Sounds like he needs his own user profile with limited permissions.  That being said, as others have mentioned, with physical access it is nearly impossible to fully lock someone out.  You could use [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to encrypt another drive that you install your games/programs to that requires your permissions to access (it also would allow you to disconnect the drive and take with you).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "erasing the history from Command Prompt".  Do you mean that you are launching games from the Run Command, and your brother is able to see the commands that you entered by hitting the down arrow after opening the Run Window?  If so, I found an [article](http://www.windows-commandline.com/how-to-clear-windows-run-history/) saying that you can try doing the following:

> 1. Open the Run Window
> 2. reg delete
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
>      /va /f
> 3. Log out and log back in

If you are talking about the [Command Prompt](http://www.bleepstatic.com/tutorials/cmdprompt/cmdprompt.gif) itself though, all you should need to do is close the Command Prompt window after finishing playing your game.  As far as I am aware, there is no history of saved commands that you have entered into Command Prompt that would be saved somewhere the way it is in the *NIX environment.

As an aside, I agree with what Chris has mentioned, about sitting your brother down and explaining why you do not want him playing this games.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to tell your little brother to stop doing that. Just prevention isn't enough. It's much better to explain him, why he isn't allowed to play these games.

But to prevent your brother, there are many solutions. But the simplest one is, if you add a password to your account:

> 1. Click on Start and then Control Panel.
> 2. Click on the User Accounts and Family Safety link. 
>    **Note**: If you're viewing the Large icons or Small icons view of Control Panel,
>      you won't see this link. Simply click on the User Accounts icon and
>      proceed to Step 4.
> 3. Click on the User Accounts link.
> 4. In the Make changes to your user account area of the User Accounts window, click the Create a password for your account link.
> 5. In the first two text boxes, enter the password you would like to start using. 
>    Entering the password twice helps to make sure that
>      you typed your new password correctly.
> 6. In the final text box, you're asked to Type a password hint. 
>    This step is optional but I highly recommend that you use it. If
>      you try logging in to Windows 7 but enter the wrong password, this
>      hint will pop up, hopefully jogging your memory.
> 7. Click the Create password button to confirm your new password.
> 8. You can now close the User Accounts window.

[Source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/create-password-windows-7.htm)

Than you only have to click <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock your pc.

Comment: This is definatly a good suggestion, but depending on how proficient his brother is at using a computer, he might have access to software like Hiren's BootCD, which would be able to remove user passwords that are put onto the computer.

Comment: @MichaelH Yes, you are right, but if you have physical access to a computer, you can access almost everything if you know how.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you to be asking about how to prevent your brother from playing games on your PC when you're not around.  If he is more adept on a computer than you are, then your chances are not good lol!

- You might try installing games on an external hard drive rather than onto your C drive and then when you're finished, remove the hard drive and put it somewhere he cannot access.
- You could create him his own profile on the PC and then deny that account access to the games directories via the security tab in the folder properties.

Comment: I've had to delete, convert to comment, or edit 4 of your answers in a row. Please stop for a minute and read the [About] and [Answer] pages before posting any more answers. Specifically, answers should be serious, to the point, and should not have any signatures added.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to the start menu search when you refer to "command prompt". The search bar in the start menu searches your entire computer, so the only way to prevent it from listing your installed games (or related files) is to disable Windows Search:

> 1. Open Services by typing services.msc in the start menu search box and press enter.
> 2. Scroll down until you find Windows Search. Right click the service, then click Properties.
> 3. Click the dropdown for Startup type and click Disabled.

---

**Alternative Answer:**

An answer to your brother-playing-violent-video-games problem entirely depends on exactly how proficient your brother is at getting into what he wants to get into. Like Chris commented, if you have physical access to a computer, you can get data from it in one way or another, if you know how.

The un-beatable way to prevent your brother from accessing certain content would be physically separating the content from your tower. Install your games on a removable hard drive that you remove when you are done playing.

The only other thing you have to rely on is permissions. Set him up with a standard user account and yourself with a password-protected administrator account. From there, [revoke read and execute permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754344.aspx) from his account on the game folders themselves. Without your password, he can't launch or otherwise view anything in them.